# WPF - Bind RadGridView to dataset with many tables

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, dataset, radgridview

First of all, i get the dataset with many tables from string of XML, for example the XML look like this :

```
class xmldummy
{    
    public static string XmlRequest = "<?xml version =\"1.0\"?>"+
                                                "<table>"+
                                                  "<row>"+
                                                    "<name>abc</name>"+
                                                    "<type>def</type>"+
                                                  "</row>"+
                                                  ...
                                                  "<row5>"+
                                                    "<name>123</name>"+
                                                    "<type>456</type>"+
                                                  "</row5>"+
                                                "<table>";
}
```

then in i have this code to read and put it in the dataset :

```
string xmlRequest = xmldummy.XmlRequest;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlReply)));
```

I though i gonna have a dataset with one table that consist of 5 rows, but instead i have a dataset with 5 tables.

then i want to bind it with RadGridView, i dont know exactly how i show all the dataset. What i've known is for 1 table :

```
gridView.DataContext = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
```

Is there any simple way so i can show all the tables to my gridView? or maybe i should combine all the tables into 1?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the XML file is not properly structured. To create a proper XML structure, ensure that the item list have the same tags, for example:

```
<table>
    <row>
       <name>Entry 1</name>
       <value>123</value>
    </row>
    <row>
       <name>Entry 2</name>
       <value>456</value>
    </row>
</table>
```

In the XML you provided, each `row` has different tag: `row1`, `row2`, this will makes the DataSet parsing invalid.

Comment: sorry for the late respond, i tried it and it works but i need those different tag for some reason and will use it later.

Comment: @Mirza No you cannot do that. That is not how XML works. If you want to attach another value to each row, put it as another tag, example:
`<row>   <name>Some name</name>  <value>Some value</value>   <key>123</key>  </row>` Or if you want to be more advanced, you can attach it on the attribute like this `<row key='1'>...</row>`, but you cannot use `ReadXml` method directly, instead provide additional XML parser of your own